# Creating a directory tree in phone gap

Tags: javascript, cordova

I know that we can create a single directory in phonegap using the following code:

```
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, onRequestFileSystemSuccess, null); 

function onRequestFileSystemSuccess(fileSystem) { 
        var entry=fileSystem.root; 
        entry.getDirectory("Folder1", {create: true, exclusive: false}, onGetDirectorySuccess, onGetDirectoryFail); 
} 

function onGetDirectorySuccess(dir) { 
      console.log("Created dir "+dir.name); 
} 

function onGetDirectoryFail(error) { 
     console.log("Error creating directory "+error.code); 
}
```

This would create a single folder "Folder1" if it does not exist.

My question is how would you create an entire directory tree at once??
ex. Folder1/Folder2

Comment: What happens when you call getDirectory with "Folder1/Folder2"?

Comment: You get an error saying failed to create directory using above code if i give Folder1/Folder2... So as a work around I have called this function twice, First to create folder1 and then folder2...to which I will actually be moving the data. I wanted something where i would be able to create both Folder1 and Folder2 if they did not exist... But right now its possible to jus create one folder at a time